# In Angular 9, how can I replace the configuration file in assets folder during an ng build?

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

I have an `Angular 6` project which I now upgraded to `Angular 9`. After upgrading I am not able to replace the .json configuration file in `assets` folder with a configuration file in `environments` folder.
I have several configuration files in the environments folder corresponding to different staging environments.
While the application is build using the below command,

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/ --configuration=staging_<number>
```

All the replacement list is mentioned in angular.json like,

```
{
  ...
  "projects":{
  ...
    "architect":{
    ...
      "build":{
      ...
      "configurations"{
        "staging_<number>": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/assets/appsettings_config.json",
                  "with": "src/environments/appsettings_config_stg_<number>.json"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": true
             ..
```

Before upgrading the replacements were working fine.
Now when I run the above command the application is build with the same configuration file which is already in the assets folder. ie, `appsettings_config.json` and not `appsettings_config_stg_<number>.json`.
What could have been the difference between Angular version 6 and 9 in the file replacement functionality?

Answer (score 2):

File replacements are meant to be used with bundles, not assets. It was a glitch that it was working before.

Angular team is trying to work on this but seems, like they have more important things (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8808).

However for a workaround see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16779